# System froze but is still accesible through ssh

Tags: ssh, freeze

I was doing some stuff on a workstation and the graphics begun to slowly deteriorate, to the point that they've become completely unresponsive. I've tried to use the SysRq key (not to reboot, just to be released from the X environment, `Alt` - `SysRq` - `r` ) but it didn't work either, I then noticed that even the CapsLock key wouldn't light on and off when pressed.

To this point I am normally able to log in to the workstation via ssh and do work.

Since this is a workstation that other people work with too, I would like to avoid a reboot and I am asking, is there any possibility to work around this problem through ssh which is still functional?

Edit:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

3.13.0-52-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 4 04:32:59 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: what desktop were you running?  And other information about the system that might let people help?

Comment: You can restart x sesion, but details are needed. If it is standard Ubuntu `sudo restart lightdm` will do it.

Comment: So I guess there is nothing I can do since I am not a sudoer

Answer (score 0):

Nothing that connects to graphics processing on the workstation works could be caused by a problem with the workstation's GPU if there is one, either with the graphics card itself or with the GPU's driver.

From the terminal via ssh run this command:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

This command will list the available proprietary graphics drivers and show the Recommended driver. Unfortunately installing the Recommended proprietary graphics driver will require a reboot to enable the driver. If you have to reboot the workstation, a benefit of this will be that any error messages that you get when booting or rebooting will sometimes help to identify what hardware device may be causing the problem.